# API to read smart card certificate in Java

Tags: java, smartcard

I want to read certificates available in my smart card.
I have PIV card inject in my machine card reader. I want to read the data from the card and use it.

Do we have any ways in Java ? I am fine with any other programming languages too.

Just to add : I have found javax.smartCard API [smart Card API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/) and WinSCard.dll API. Still I am not sure weather that will be helpful to me or not.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to use a smartcard with Java is to use the PKCS#11 API. Usually the smart card software components contain a PKCS#11 library (.dll/.so file(s)) which can be loaded by Java and used.

In the end you can access the smart card from Java side using the [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) interface (via the `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11` provider).

See also:

- [JDK 8 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html)
- [SO questions tagged Java and PKCS#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+pkcs%2311)

Comment: Just to provide you more clarification, I have to read digital signature from the PIV card and want to use in web application and verify the signature.

Comment: You mean you want to use the smartcard to create a digital signature on some data. I already showed you the way via KeyStore. Using that you can load a key and use it for creating a signature.